# Randomly append items from a list to a matrix list

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a game.  I have a list.  I want to take the items in this list and randomly append them to indexes in a list matrix.  Think about a grid and an item moving around randomly through this grid.

```
import random


fishlist = ["salmon", "carp", "bass", "catfish"]


grid = [
            [1,2,3],
            [4,5,6],
            [7,8,9],
            ]
```

I want to replace each of those numbers with a random fish.  From there I want the fish to be able to move around the grid.  What is the best way to go about this?  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
>>> grid = [
            [1,2,3],
            [4,5,6],
            [7,8,9],
            ]
>>> fishlist = ["salmon", "carp", "bass", "catfish"]

>>> [r.__setitem__(i,random.choice(fishlist)) for r in grid for i in xrange(0,len(r))]
[None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
>>> print grid
[['salmon', 'salmon', 'carp'], ['carp', 'salmon', 'bass'], ['bass', 'salmon', 'bass']]
>>>
```

To Move the fish try this

```
>>> def Move(grid):
    rSrc=random.choice(grid)
    rDest=random.choice(grid)
    a,b=random.randint(0,len(rSrc)-1),random.randint(0,len(rSrc)-1)
    rSrc[a],rDest[b]=rDest[b],rSrc[a]
    >>> grid
[['carp', 'catfish', 'catfish'], ['catfish', 'carp', 'salmon'], ['catfish', 'catfish', 'carp']]
>>> Move(grid)
>>> grid
[['catfish', 'catfish', 'carp'], ['catfish', 'carp', 'salmon'], ['catfish', 'catfish', 'carp']]
>>>
```

Using Loop

```
>>> grid = [
            [1,2,3],
            [4,5,6],
            [7,8,9],
            ]
>>> fishlist = ["salmon", "carp", "bass", "catfish"]
>>> for r in grid:
    for i in xrange(0,len(r)):
        r[i]=random.choice(fishlist)


>>> grid
[['bass', 'catfish', 'carp'], ['catfish', 'salmon', 'salmon'], ['bass', 'salmon', 'catfish']]
>>>
```

Comment: The loop is what I was able to come up with as well.  For the Move function, is there any way to move the fish between different lists?

Comment: The above code (Move) would actually swap between different list

Answer (score 0):

You can create a list that contains the mapping from index to fish

```
import random  
random.seed()  # init the random seed
fish = [0] * 11   # init the array  
for i in range(1,11):     #for each indexes from 1 to 10
    fish[i] = random.choice(fishlist)
```

then, for each grid

grid_fish = [[0,0,0],[0,0,0,],[0,0,0]]  # init the fish grid

```
for i in range(0,len(grid):
   for j in range(0,len(grid[i])):
       grid_fish[i][j] = fish[ grid[i][j] ]
```

for each item in grid, get the name of fish based on its index from array `fish`, and put the result into `grid_fish`